# Localizing a string containing list of names

Tags: java, localization

I have string containing a list of name like below:
"John asked Kim, Kelly, Lee and Bob about the new year plans". The number of names in the list can very. 
How can I localize this in Java?
I am thinking about ResourceBundle and MessageFormat. How will I write the pattern for this in MessageFormat?
Is there any better approach?

Comment: Can you give an example of what the string would look like with a different localisation?

Comment: My problem is more to do with Formatting (inserting names dynamically to the localized string pattern). something like '{1} asked {2} and {3} about new year plans'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
"{0} asked {1} about the new year plans"
```

where 0 is the first name and 1 is a comma-separated list of the other names.

Hope this helps.

Comment: {1} is cannot be a comma separated list, it should contain 'and' before the last name. Also 'and' needs to be localized.

Comment: Then you will need to have "1" be a built by another formatter based on the number of people: "{0}" (or no format) when there is only one person, or "{0} and {1}" when there are more than one - 0 becomes a comma separated list of all but the last person, and 1 is the last person.

Answer (score 15):

Localizing an (inline) list is more than just translating the word “and.” CLDR deals with the issue of formatting lists, check out their [page on lists](http://cldr.unicode.org/translation/lists). I’m afraid ICU doesn’t have support to this yet, so you might need to code it separately.

Another issue is that you cannot expect to be able to use names as such in sentences like this. Many languages require the object to be in an inclined form, for example. In Finnish, your sample sentence would read as “John kysyi Kimiltä, Kellyltä, Leeltä ja Bobilta uudenvuoden suunnitelmista.” So you may need to find out and include different inclined forms of the names. Moreover, if the language used does not have Latin alphabet, you may need transliterated forms of the names (e.g., in Arabic, John is جون). There are other problems as well. In Russian, the verb corresponding to “asked” depends on the gender of the subject (e.g., спросила vs. спросил).

I know this sounds complex, but localization is often complex. If you target a limited set of languages only, things can be much easier, so it is important to defined your goals—perhaps accepting some simplifications that may result in grammatically incorrect expressions. But for localization that is to cover a wide range languages, you may need to make the generating function localized. That is, you would have, for each language, a function that accepts a list of names as arguments and returns a string representing the statement, possibly using resource files containing information (transliterated form, different inclined form, gender) about proper names that may appear.

In some situations, you might even consider generating the sentence in English, then sending it to an online translator. For example, Google Translator can deal with some of the issues that I mentioned. It surely produces wrong translations a lot, but for sentences with grammatically very simple structure, it might be a pragmatic solution, if you can accept some amount of errors. If you consider trying this, make sure you test sufficiently how the automatic translator can handle the specific sentences you will use. Quite often you can improve the results by reformulating the sentences. Dividing a sentence with several clauses into separate sentences often helps. But even your simple sentence causes problems in automatic translation.

You might avoid some complications if you can reformulate the sentence structure, e.g. so that all the nouns appear in the subject position and you avoid “packed” expressions like “new year plans.” For example, “John asked what plans Kim, Kelly, Lee, and Bob have for the new year” would be simpler, both for automatic translation and for pattern-based localization.

Comment: ICU versions 50 and later provides an API for this (ListFormatter).  See http://site.icu-project.org/download/50: "Change Java util.ListFormat to text.ListFormatter and other updates, use CLDR data (#9369, #9420), port to C++ (#7168)"

Comment: @Fredrik, ListFormatter is meant to handle punctuation in lists (e.g. “A, B and C” vs. “A, B, and C”) and the word for “and”. There are many other problems in localizing sentences like the one in the question.

Comment: I know what it does; my comment was a clarification to the "I’m afraid ICU doesn’t have support to this yet" bit in your reply.  ListFormatter is the API for the CLDR data you mention.

Answer (score 2):

I see an answer was already accepted, I'm just adding this here as an alternative. The code has hard coded values for the data, but is only meant to present an idea that can be refined:

```
MessageFormat people = new MessageFormat("{0} asked {1,choice,0#no one|1#{2}|2#{2} and {3}|2<{2}, and {3}} about the new year plans");
String john = "John";
Object[][] parties = new Object[][] { {john, 0}, {john, 1, "Kim"}, {john, 2, "Kim", "Kelly}, {john, 4, "Kim, Kelly, Lee", "Bob"}};
for (final Object[] strings : parties) {
    System.out.println(people.format(strings));
}
```

This outputs the following:

```
John asked no one about the new year plans
John asked Kim about the new year plans
John asked Kim and Kelly about the new year plans
John asked Kim, Kelly, Lee, and Bob about the new year plans
```

Determining the number of names that is used for the 2nd argument and creating the comma-delimited string for the 3rd argument isn't displayed in that sample, but can easily be done instead of using the hard coded values I used.

Answer (score 1):

For localization, the normal approach is to use external language packs, which is a file contains the text you're going to display, assign each text a name/key, then load the text in the program by the key.

Answer (score 0):

You could combine your ResourceBundle (for I18N) with a MessageFormat (to replace placeholders with the names) : "{0} asked {1} about the new year plans"

It would be up to you to prepare the names beforehand, though.