# i18n with variable number of parameters

Tags: angularjs, internationalization

Sorry if the title is too vague, because I don't know the right term for this situation.

What is the appropriate translation string for these sentences:

- I have `a book`.
- I have `a book` and `a pen`.
- I have `a book`, `a pencil` and `a pen`.

I'm working with Angular and i18n.

Comment: In our company we use keys like <where it is used in the application>.<description of words> e.g.: `itemlist.singlePen` and `itemlist.singleBook`

Comment: @Thomas: Thank you for your response. Maybe my question is confusing. But the problem I want to solve is the ```and``` word, and the ```,```, in this case, the number of items is dynamic.

Comment: you make different keys for single and plural. (ps your question is confusing du to not highlighting "and" and "," but np). I suggest combining key's for the 3rd string like: `thirdSentence={itemlist.singlePen}, {itemlist.singleBook} and {itemlist.singlePencil}`

Comment: @Thomas: Thanks for your solution. I think there should be a more simple way no? Because what happens if the number of items goes up to 10, and what if there are two places like this in one sentence? For example, I have ```a book```, ```a pencil``` and ```a pen``` and I like playing ```football```, ```basketball``` and ```golf```. (sounds silly but just example)

Comment: I work for a big company and it is possible that we are doing it wrong, but I'm almost sure you have to solve this in code logic like: `if(books == 1){use singular}else{use plural}`

Comment: @Thomas: Thanks a lot, I'll try this and if there's better solution I will refactor later.

Comment: @Thomas: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8448013/1974153 this is an interesting reference.

Comment: we use that as well: it just still doesn't change the word, it's used for using a number variable for plural: `{0} cows can be the amount of cows` but you still need a separate key for `1 cow`

Comment: One more reference: in Rails, there's a function called ```to_sentence```, here is the javascript implementation: https://gist.github.com/mudge/1076046